# Can blender make online games

Tags: game-engine

Is there possibility for one to make realtime online blender games? Tried looking up the net but info very scant.

Comment: yep. but you'll need something like BlendforWeb

Comment: see this blog section about games https://www.blend4web.com/en/community/tag/34/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with "realtime blender online games".

## Blender

Blender is a model editor and not sufficient to act as a game frame work.

## BGE

The BGE is a full fledged game engine and can be used to create "realtime games".

There is no build-in network support. You can communicate over a network via Python. This means you have to implement it by yourself (strong Python and network skills required).

## Other Game Engines

You can use Blender to create assets to serve a game running on other game engines. It is up to this other engines to provide network support.